error when using \thetcbcounter in nameref in tcolorbox definition
Problem
I want to have a custom nameref string for my tcolorboxes, but I also want to include the \thetcbcounter in the nameref string.
I tried doing this with the following code in the tcolorbox's definition, which leads to the following error.
nameref={Proposition \thetcbcounter: {#3}}

<argument> Proposition {\thetcbcounter 
                                       }: {Absolute value property \dots }
l.1 ...:absValueProperty7}}}{2}{tcb@cnt@proof.1.1}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.

This error appears in my filename.proofs file (which stores a list of all the proof tcolorboxes used in my document so it can display them later), and inside of my proof tcolorbox when I reference another tcolorbox using nameref (namely, prop tcolorboxes), the \thetcbcounter part displays the proof box's \thetcbcounter value instead of the original's, which is what I want.
MWE
Code
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Floats
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Hyperlinks
\usepackage[
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    colorlinks=false,
    linkcolor=black,
    pdfencoding=auto,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    psdextra
]{
    hyperref
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=propositions]{prop}{ m O{} !O{} }% title, label, other
{%
    title={Proposition.},
    list entry={\textit{Proposition \protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}}{#1}}, % Use prop. title in list entry
    label={po:#2},
    nameref={Proposition {\thetcbcounter}: {#1}},
    before upper={\textit{Proposition \thetcbcounter~({#1}):}\\},
    #3
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=proofs]{proof}{ O{} O{} !O{} }% label of theorem, label of proof, other
{%
    title={Proof.},
    list entry={\textit{Proof \protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}}{\nameref{#1}}}, % Use theorem title in list entry
    label={pr:#2},
    nameref={Proof \thetcbcounter ({\nameref{#1}})},
    before upper={\textit{Proof \thetcbcounter~(\nameref{#1}):}\\},  % Uses the wrong `\tcbcounter` in the "proposition"'s `nameref`
    #3
}



\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part*{List of results}

\tcblistof[\section*]{propositions}{Propositions}
\tcblistof[\section*]{proofs}{Proofs}

\newpage

\part{Introduction part}

\section{Introduction section}

\begin{prop}{Absolute value property \dots}[absValueProperty7]
    If \dots
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}[po:absValueProperty7][myproofone]
    First assume that \dots % Rest of the proof and labels work
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[po:absValueProperty7][myprooftwo]  % Just to show that the numbering is wrong (see image 2)
    Again, first assume that \dots % Rest of the proof and labels work
\end{proof}

\end{document}

Images



P.S. I wanted to use \NewTcbTheorem at first, but decided it might be easier to get the formatting I want using custom defined tcolorboxes, hence the custom ones are in use (in my actual document, not the MWE) instead of using a \NewTcbTheorem, which may have made the process a bit easier. ;-;

yes your example is quite big. And I bet that all the colors, title and other setups are not needed to describe the problem.

@UlrikeFischer I have shortened (more than halved) the MWE with an edit. Hope this is easier to work with.

It seems that \thetcbcounter isn't defined when nameref is used.
As a workaround, you can use \ref instead. For the proposition:
nameref={Proposition \ref{po:#2}  : {#1}},

and for the proof:
nameref={Proof \ref{pr:#2} ({\nameref{#1}})},

Example:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Floats
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

% Hyperlinks
\usepackage[
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    colorlinks=false,
    linkcolor=black,
    pdfencoding=auto,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    psdextra
]{
    hyperref
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=propositions]{prop}{ m O{} !O{} }% title, label, other
{%
    title={Proposition.},
    list entry={\textit{Proposition \protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}}{#1}}, % Use prop. title in list entry
    label={po:#2},
    nameref={Proposition \ref{po:#2}  : {#1}},
    before upper={\textit{Proposition \thetcbcounter~({#1}):}\\},
    #3
}

\NewTColorBox[auto counter, number within=section, list inside=proofs]{proof}{ O{} O{} !O{} }% label of theorem, label of proof, other
{%
    title={Proof.},
    list entry={\textit{Proof \protect\numberline{\thetcbcounter}}{\nameref{#1}}}, % Use theorem title in list entry
    label={pr:#2},
    nameref={Proof \ref{pr:#2} ({\nameref{#1}})},
    before upper={\textit{Proof \thetcbcounter~(\nameref{#1}):}\\},
    #3
}


\begin{document}

\part*{List of results}

\tcblistof[\section*]{propositions}{Propositions}
\tcblistof[\section*]{proofs}{Proofs}

\section{Introduction section}

\begin{prop}{Absolute value property \dots}[absValueProperty7]
    If \dots
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}[po:absValueProperty7][myproofone]
    First assume that \dots
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[po:absValueProperty7][myprooftwo]
    Again, first assume that \dots
\end{proof}

\begin{prop}{Another proposition \dots}[another]
    If \dots
\end{prop}

\begin{proof}[po:another][myproofthree]
    First assume that \dots
\end{proof}

\end{document}



Thanks for this! Should I submit this as a bug to the tcolorbox package repository, or leave it be like this because it's not a bug in the package but rather just how counters work with nameref? Any advice?

@BrightBulb123 Well, you can. In fact I'm not sure this is a bug, maybe rather the way nameref is implemented.
